# Increased encrypted partition size but Gnome Files still thinks it's small

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, encryption

I have an installation of Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1 running in VirtualBox 5.2.20. When I first installed it, I made the mistake of giving the VDI a capacity of only 20 GB. That filled up fairly quickly, so I decided to enlarge the VDI and home partition.

The home partition is encrypted with LUKS. I used VBoxManager to increase the capacity of the VDI to 100 GB, then I booted the Ubuntu VM and installed GParted to enlarge the partition. It worked perfectly, the machine boots fine every time and Gnome Disks shows the partition scheme exactly as expected.

The problem now is that Files thinks the partition capacity is still 19.2 GB and still shows me constant warnings about low disk space. At this point the disk has 18.1 GB of data on it, so it's not "full" (according to Files) yet. I've been googling but haven't found a solution yet. Any ideas? Also, if the data on it goes over what Files thinks the capacity is, will that cause problems?

Comment: The command `sudo cryptsetup resize --size  <new-size> encrypted-volume`. Let me check the entry for new-size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed out on the `LUKS` resize part:

```
resize <name>

              Resizes an active mapping <name>.

              If --size (in sectors) is not specified, the size of the underlying block device is
              used. Note that this does not change the raw device geometry, it just  changes  how
              many sectors of the raw device are represented in the mapped device.
```

So the command `sudo cryptsetup resize <encrypted-volume>` should inform `LUKS` about the new size.

The basic steps are:

1. Boot the desktop, live CD. Use gparted (or any tool) to put unallocated space adjacent, and to the left of your Crypt partition.
   Enlarge the Partition storing the crypt with fdisk.
2. Reboot ~ You should always reboot after changing your partition table with fdisk.
3. Boot the desktop, live CD. Install & configure the tools (lvm2 and cryptsetup).

   - `sudo apt update && sudo apt install lvm2 cryptsetup`
   - `sudo modprobe dm-crypt`
   - `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 crypt1`
4. Enlarge the Crypt with cryptsetup.

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup resize <encrypted-volume>
   ```

**Note:**

Steps `1` and `2` you have done already so you should be looking at step 3, but read through that link provided to understand what is going on.

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Specifically, I followed the "Detailed resizing ~ Enlarging an encrypted partition" section in your link and it fixed the problem perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome and Happy holidays!